# Spring Batch MongoDB Dependency Issue

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-batch

I'm having trouble getting my Spring Batch application to run, due to the following exception;

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.findMergedAnnotation(Ljava/lang/reflect/AnnotatedElement;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/annotation/Annotation;
at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.findAnnotation(BasicPersistentEntity.java:371)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.BasicMongoPersistentEntity.<init>(BasicMongoPersistentEntity.java:80)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.MongoMappingContext.createPersistentEntity(MongoMappingContext.java:91)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.MongoMappingContext.createPersistentEntity(MongoMappingContext.java:39)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:309)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:180)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:140)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:67)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.getPersistentEntity(MongoTemplate.java:1992)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.save(MongoTemplate.java:957)
at org.springframework.batch.item.data.MongoItemWriter.doWrite(MongoItemWriter.java:128)
at org.springframework.batch.item.data.MongoItemWriter$1.beforeCommit(MongoItemWriter.java:156)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationUtils.triggerBeforeCommit(TransactionSynchronizationUtils.java:95)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.triggerBeforeCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:928)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:740)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:726)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy45.commit(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:150)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:271)
at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:81)
at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:368)
at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:257)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:200)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:64)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:67)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:169)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:134)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:306)
at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:135)
at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:128)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy46.run(Unknown Source)
at com.diona.batch.personload.Application.main(Application.java:53)
```

I believe the problem is because I should be using spring-core 4.2 or later when this method was added, although I'm having trouble interpreting the maven dependency hierarchy to pinpoint the problem.

I'm using Eclipse and have generated the dependency hierachy and focussed in on spring-core. The results are below;

[spring-core hierarcy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJjrS.jpg)

What is causing me to be using spring-core 4.0.7 here instead of what I need to be using, which is 4.2+?

Thanks,

Bic

PS Updating to add my POM;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.diona.batch</groupId>
<artifactId>person-load-batch</artifactId>
<version>0.1.0</version>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring.boot.version>1.4.1.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
    <spring.batch.version>3.0.7.RELEASE</spring.batch.version>
    <spring.data.releasetrain>Hopper-SR4</spring.data.releasetrain>
    <oracle.driver.version>11.2.0</oracle.driver.version>
    <mongodb.driver.version>2.11.2</mongodb.driver.version>
    <junit.version>3.8.1</junit.version>
</properties>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath></relativePath>
</parent>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-releasetrain</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.data.releasetrain}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>

    <!-- spring boot -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
    </dependency>  
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>        
    </dependency>       

    <!-- spring batch -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.batch.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- ORACLE database driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>${oracle.driver.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- MongoDB database driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>${mongodb.driver.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JUnit framework -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: You should show the contents of your pom.

Comment: Updated to add pom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing Spring Boot starters with Spring Data release train stuff. In addition you're using a very old version of Spring Boot with the latest Spring Data. If you're using Spring Boot just have your POM like this:

Also refer to [Getting Started with Spring Data Mongo](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mongodb/)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.diona.batch</groupId>
<artifactId>person-load-batch</artifactId>
<version>0.1.0</version>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring.boot.version>1.4.1.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
    <oracle.driver.version>11.2.0</oracle.driver.version>
    <junit.version>3.8.1</junit.version>
</properties>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <!-- spring boot -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
    </dependency>  
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>        
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- ORACLE database driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>${oracle.driver.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JUnit framework -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: I need the spring data stuff for what I want to do - which is basically reading from an Oracle database and writing to mongodb. If I update the spring boot to the version you're recommending, will I be ok to use the latest release trainspring data release train?

Comment: @bicster, you're already including `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`. You will have everything you need to read from Oracle (you've included the driver). I've updated my answer to include the MongoDB stuff.

Comment: The question is though - why? I thought I had to import everything related to spring data in, but I'm guesssing spring boot is doing that for me with the spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb dependency? I'm new to spring so this is a little confusing still!